# Want to enter data in next line in file handling . I have used tried to use ‘\n’ but its not working

Tags: python, file-handling

def addData(callno,bookname,author,year,qty):

```
  outfil=open('taxt.txt','a')
  outfil.write(str('\n'+callno).strip()+str(',').strip() + str(bookname).strip()+str(',').strip()+ str(author).strip()+str(',').strip()+ str(year).strip()+str(',').strip()+ str(qty).strip())


  outfil.close
```

Answer (score 1):

The strip() method strips all whitespace, including newlines. You need to call strip() before you add the `\n` character, not after.

Also, you don't need to call str() and strip() on things that are already strings.

```
  outfil=open('taxt.txt','a')
  outfil.write('\n' + str(callno).strip() + ',' + str(bookname).strip() + ',' + str(author).strip() + ',' + str(year).strip() + ',' + str(qty).strip())
  outfil.close
```

By the way, you can simplify this using the `with` operator, str.join, and a generator expression.

```
with open("taxt.txt", "a") as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n" + ",".join(str(value).strip() for value in (callno, bookname, author, year, qty)))
```